# TypeError:slices, not numpy.float64

Tags: python

I want to write my matlab code to python, there is some problems, it gives erros "
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64". I cant understand what main problem is, mydata types? should i convert data types? I know matlab coding but now I'm learning python, maybe thats my main problem?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed May 27 21:56:26 2020

@author: 
"""
import numpy as np
coord=[]
coord = np.array([[13, 44, 23],
       [42, 49, 49],
       [3, 52, 64],
       [4, 20, 26],
       [34, 61, 33],
       [35, 62, 63],
       [36, 63, 69],
       [37, 32, 22],
       [38, 32, 35],
       [39, 59, 15],
       [40, 5, 6],
       [41, 10, 17],
       [42, 21, 10],
       [43, 5, 64],
       [44, 30, 15],
       [45, 39, 10],
       [46, 32, 39],
       [47, 25, 32],
       [48, 25, 55],
       [49, 48, 28],
       [50, 56, 37],
       [51, 30, 23]])
city=len(coord)
best_solution=[]
best_fitness=100000000
pop_size=100  
CR=0.8 # %YÜZDE 90 OLASILIKLA CAPRAZLANIYOR.
MR=0.5
MaxIter=5000



# distance = np.zeros((coord.shape[0], coord.shape[0]))
distance = np.zeros([city,city])

for i in range(city):
    for j in range(city):
        distance[i][j] = np.sqrt((coord[i][1] - coord[j][1]) ** 2 + (coord[i][2] - coord[j][2]) ** 2)

population=np.zeros([pop_size,city])     
for i in range(pop_size):
    population[i][:]=np.random.permutation(city)

fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])   

for i in range(pop_size):
              fitness[0][i]=0
              for j in range(city-1):
                  fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
```

here is matlab version of my codes.

```
fitness(i)=fitness(i)+distance(population(i,j),population(i,j+1));
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]` to mean? In particular, why are there *two* pairs of square brackets around the outside?

Comment: "I'm learning a different programming language" is never the problem. It's your opportunity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
```

This means:

- Make a list that has one item in it, computed as `population[i][j]`.
- Use `population[i][j+1]` as an index into that list.
- Take the result from that indexing, and use **that** as an index into `distance`.

But `population[i][j+1]` is a floating-point number, so it is not a valid index into the `[population[i][j]]` list.

You presumably wanted just `distance[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]` (note the extra pair of square brackets is removed from the outside).

If you *did* mean for it to work that way, then the problem is that `population[i][j+1]` doesn't pull an integer index out of the `coord` array, because the `dtype` of this array is the default (`np.float64`) - that is to say, Numpy arrays store floating-point values unless you tell them otherwise, even if you write integers when describing the data. To fix that, pass the appropriate keyword argument when you create the array: `coord = np.array(... , dtype=np.int)`.

Comment: thanks i solved problem with adding "dtype=np.int" too all of arrays ending.